# How can I install rexecd on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, xinetd

I tried to install rexecd executing this codes:

```
apt-get install xinetd
apt-get install rsh-server
```

But, following the steps found on a web page, I try access to  `/etc/xinetd.d/rsh`, `/etc/xinetd.d/rlogin`  and `/etc/xinetd.d/rexec`, I can't find them, so I can't configure them.

What can I do for install rexecd?